# Trouble fetching Google calendar event exceptions by event id in Java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, gdata-java-client

I've been working with the Gdata API for Java (v2), and have figured out how to fetch events by their id. However, I'm having trouble fetching exceptions to recurring events.

For a regular event, I would fetch it as such:

```
CalendarEventEntry event = getCalendarService().getEntry(new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/"+googleCalId+"/private/full/"+eventId), CalendarEventEntry.class);
```

and the url being queried would look something like this:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/772olgd23vedk7cmvmqgcke5jps%40group.calendar.google.com/private/full/6qlnf002ge3kh6fmp3i6skbuk
```

And it fetches with no issue!

Easy peasy.

However, when I try to fetch an event that is an exception to a recurring event using the same method, I run into problems. The url of the repeating event would be

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/772olgd23vedk7cmvmqgcke5jps%40group.calendar.google.com/private/full/6qlnf002ge3kh6fmp3i6skbuk_20120112
```

Same url, with _20120112 appended. The nature of the problem:

```
com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Error</title>
<style type="text/css">body {font-family: arial,sans-serif}</style></head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#ffffff"><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td rowspan="3" width="1%" nowrap><b><font face="times" size="10"><font color="#0039b6">G</font> <font color="#c41200">o</font> <font color="#f3c518">o</font> <font color="#0039b6">g</font> <font color="#30a72f">l</font> <font color="#c41200">e</font></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#3366cc"><font face="arial,sans-serif" color="#ffffff"><b>Error</b></font></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
<blockquote>Cannot access the calendar you requested</blockquote>
<p></p>
<div style="background:#3366cc; width:1px; height:4px"></div></body></html>

        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:591)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getEntry(Service.java:1352)
        at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getEntry(GoogleService.java:567)
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getEntry(Service.java:1278)
        at com.testsoftware.google.CalendarServiceManager.getEventById(CalendarServiceManager.java:410)
        ...stack of my program here...
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

Anybody have any ideas why this is happening or better ways to go about this?

Comment: I've posted my question here as well: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/community/forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-calendar-api%2FbKtEDLPySBc%2Fdiscussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much testing and development, I've concluded that you can fetch exceptions to repeating events in the same way one fetches normal events, with one caveat: they can't be canceled.

Man what a headache :-P